# JW player showing blank page in Internet explorer with no errors

Tags: jquery, html, flash, jwplayer

I want to play a video in all browser. This my below code is working fine in `chrome` and `firefox` but not working in IE8 or lower.

Blank page coming with no errors. Also i need your kind suggestion to improve this code for TABLET, All Browsers,IPHONE, and also on MAC.

Is there any suggestion for improving performance in all IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>

        <!-- Basic Page Needs
      ================================================== -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
            <title>
                Demostration of ektuhi video
            </title>
            <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/irhCxKvuEeKSqiIACpYGxA.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
            html,body { height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
            #player {
            height:100%;
            width:100%; padding:0; margin:-3px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id='my-video'></div>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    jwplayer('my-video').setup({
                        flashplayer: 'player.swf',
                        file: 'http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-364766.mp4',
                image: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/phoenix/download_video_preview.png',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        stretching: 'exactfit'
                    });
                </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try specifying player height in `px` instead of `%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
flashplayer: 'player.swf',
```

Not needed for JW6.